# Python 2.7 install coreNLP error, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute spawn and stanfordCoreNLP have no attrivbute "corenlp"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to install CoreNLP in anaconde python2.7, as this way: "A Python wrapper for Stanford CoreNLP (see also: PyPI page)", but show  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute spawn.
Exception AttributeError: "stanfordCoreNLP instance have no attrivbute "corenlp" in bound method stanfordCoreNLP.**del__of <__main**.stanfordCoreNLP instance at 0x000000002A45348> ignored".
Pexpect has been installed and update.

Comment: Are you running the code on Windows?